# How to prevent mixture of custom string types?

Tags: typescript, tsc

Suppose we have two custom types, both derived from string, and two corresponding variables.

```
type A = string;
let a: A = "a";

type B = string;
let b: B = "b";
```

How can the code or the compiler configuration be changed, so that the following will raise a type mismatch error?

```
a = b;
```

Comment: It can't. TypeScript is *structurally*, not *nominally* typed. There are workarounds like "branded" types, or in this case you could use string literal types if the possible values don't overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript has a **structural** type system, not a **nominal** type system. In practical terms, this means that it is the *shape* of things that matter, not what you happen to *name* them. So it is not possible to restrict things given your example.

If `A` and `B` can only be assigned from a set of known strings at compile time, it is possible to represent them more accurately.

Eg:

`type A = 'one' | 'two';`

`type B = 'three' | 'four';`

These types cannot be assigned to one another